# What is a good Ubuntu application for adjusting the screen colour balance and contrast?

Tags: software-center, display, resolution, screen, color-management

It seems that the screen of my Samsung Series 7 Chronos laptop has a weird white glare. (try seeing how the pdf file on the Overleaf website looks like!)

I installed "redshift" but that is just adding a whole lot of red tint to everything. It seems like I am looking through a red glass!

What is the best application out there which will solve this problem?